# Choose the right rotatiton and translation matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, translation, triangulation

I'm trying to choose the right `R` and `t` matrices obtained from SVD decomposition with opencv. 
According to *Hartley et al.*, I have to triangulate the points with the four possible combinations `[R|t]` and I'll see which combination projects the point in front of both cameras. But my problem here is that I always find 2 possible combinations. How can it be possible?
I do an iterative triangulation. I took the code from [here](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter4_StructureFromMotion/FindCameraMatrices.cpp). 
This is my algorithm

- p1 //points in frame 1
- p2 //points in frame 2
- posibles combinatios of `[R|t]`:
- R1t1
- R1t2
- R2t1
- R2t2
- for 0 to p1.size():
- Take one point (p1[i]=x1 , p2[i]=x2)
- triangulation (x1,x2,cam1,R1t1)
- triangulation (x1,x2,cam1,R1t2)
- triangulation (x1,x2,cam1,R2t1)
- triangulation (x1,x2,cam1,R2t2)

I always get 2 points with z<0 and 2 points with z>0.

I don't know how to choose between those 2 z>0 points.

Thanks

Comment: Can you link the paper (or atleast the title) if it is relevant? Searching *Hartley et al* is most definitely not sufficient enough information.

Comment: Sure! [http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf] P. 259-260 @RollenD'Souza